# Converting comma delimited column to list in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, csv

I'm quite new to the R language and not quite sure how to do this one.
If I have a tsv (tab separated file) and read into a table via something like:

```
> table <- read.delim(file='test.tsv',sep='\t',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    id              features
1. 131  FeatureA,FeatureB,FeatureC,
2. 132  FeatureA,FeatureD,FeatureE,FeatureF
3. 135  FeatureD,FeatureE,FeatureC
4. 139  FeatureF,FeatureB
```

I'd like to be able to visualize the clusterings of features, but to leverage this in R I'd need to change the type of the column named feature into a list.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please share your desired output. Making a `list` of the features column should be as easy as `strsplit(table$features, ",")` but I'm not sure if that's the type of output you're looking for.

Comment: Ideally I would like the second column to be indexable, e.g. if I want to access the 2nd row's 2nd feature I could use [2,2[2]] which would return 'FeatureD'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My "splitstackshape" package was written to deal with these types of tasks. You can explore the `concat.split` family of functions.

Here are a few examples:

As a `list`. (But the function sorts the output--you'd do better off with `strsplit` until I add an option to *not* sort the output).

```
library(splitstackshape)
x1 <- concat.split.list(mydf, split.col="features", sep=",", drop = TRUE)
x1
#     id                          features_list
# 1. 131           FeatureA, FeatureB, FeatureC
# 2. 132 FeatureA, FeatureD, FeatureE, FeatureF
# 3. 135           FeatureD, FeatureE, FeatureC
# 4. 139                     FeatureF, FeatureB
str(x1)
# 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ id           : int  131 132 135 139
#  $ features_list:List of 4
#   ..$ : chr  "FeatureA" "FeatureB" "FeatureC"
#   ..$ : chr  "FeatureA" "FeatureD" "FeatureE" "FeatureF"
#   ..$ : chr  "FeatureD" "FeatureE" "FeatureC"
#   ..$ : chr  "FeatureF" "FeatureB"
```

As a "wide" `data.frame`:

```
x2 <- concat.split.multiple(mydf, split.col="features", sep=",")
x2
#     id features_1 features_2 features_3 features_4
# 1. 131   FeatureA   FeatureB   FeatureC       <NA>
# 2. 132   FeatureA   FeatureD   FeatureE   FeatureF
# 3. 135   FeatureD   FeatureE   FeatureC       <NA>
# 4. 139   FeatureF   FeatureB       <NA>       <NA>
```

As a "long" `data.frame`:

```
x3 <- concat.split.multiple(mydf, split.cols="features", seps=",", direction="long")
x3
#     id time features
# 1  131    1 FeatureA
# 2  132    1 FeatureA
# 3  135    1 FeatureD
# 4  139    1 FeatureF
# 5  131    2 FeatureB
# 6  132    2 FeatureD
# 7  135    2 FeatureE
# 8  139    2 FeatureB
# 9  131    3 FeatureC
# 10 132    3 FeatureE
# 11 135    3 FeatureC
# 12 139    3     <NA>
# 13 131    4     <NA>
# 14 132    4 FeatureF
# 15 135    4     <NA>
# 16 139    4     <NA>
```

---

#### Update, based on your comment:

Here's the result of `strsplit` directly, as I mentioned in the comment. Note the approach to extraction.

```
> mydf$featuresList <- strsplit(mydf$features, ",")
> mydf
    id                            features                           featuresList
1. 131         FeatureA,FeatureB,FeatureC,           FeatureA, FeatureB, FeatureC
2. 132 FeatureA,FeatureD,FeatureE,FeatureF FeatureA, FeatureD, FeatureE, FeatureF
3. 135          FeatureD,FeatureE,FeatureC           FeatureD, FeatureE, FeatureC
4. 139                   FeatureF,FeatureB                     FeatureF, FeatureB
> mydf[, "featuresList"][[2]]
[1] "FeatureA" "FeatureD" "FeatureE" "FeatureF"
> mydf[, "featuresList"][[2]][2]
[1] "FeatureD"
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use strsplit:

```
table$list.features = strsplit(table$features,",")
```

you might also want to create indicator variables for these features:

```
table[unique(unlist(table$list.features))]=0
for (i in 1:nrow(table)) table[i,table$list.features[[i]]]=1
```

Comment: I think that `strsplit` is already taken care of by both my comment and my existing answer. Your approach to tabulation is likely to not be the most efficient. Additionally, that's covered with the "splitstackshape" package too: `concat.split.expanded(mydf, "features", type="character", fill=0)` :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, both answers here help me learn how to accomplish this task.